# Issue including elFinder and JQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I'm trying to setup an elFinder window on my website. So I downloaded the latest release of from GitHub and followed [it's instructions](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Install).

I included every file they asked for:

```
<!-- elFinder -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/elfinder/js/elfinder.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/elfinder/js/i18n/elfinder.nl.js"></script>

<!-- JQuery UI -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/js/jquery-ui/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/js/jquery-ui/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/js/jquery-ui/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/js/jquery-ui/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.timepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/js/jquery-ui/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/js/jquery-ui/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.droppable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/js/jquery-ui/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.selectable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/js/jquery-ui/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/js/jquery-ui/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/js/jquery-ui/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>
```

And I include this into my `head`-section as well:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {
        var elf = $('#elfinder').elfinder({
            lang: 'nl',             // language (OPTIONAL)
            url : '../includes/elfinder/php/connector.php'  // connector URL (REQUIRED)
        }).elfinder('instance');            
    });
</script>
```

But for some reason, all I get is this image:
[image]

But those files are, obviously, included... So I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong since I can't get my finger on the issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you combine the jQuery UI files into one?

**Yes** the order of includes does matter.

Here a **[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K8ALN/)**.

Here is the code

### HTML

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://elfinder.org/demo/css/elfinder.min.css" />
</head>


<div id="elfinder"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://elfinder.org/demo/js/elfinder.min.js" ></script>​
```

### Javascript

```
$().ready(function() {
   var f = $('#elfinder').elfinder({
       url : '/connector'
   }).elfinder('instance');
});​
```

Comment: I see your working demo and I've done exactly the same thing, but for some reason, the elFinder isn't showing at all... Just a big, empty, white page. Is the `url`-path in the javascript important? To what does it have to link to?

Comment: The `url` path is the only required option. It has to link to the `connector.php` I see in github you can find this file in `elfinder/php/connector.php`

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help! Apparently, I had some other javascript blocks in my header which prevented the elFinder from executing! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing the order of inclusion?

```
<!-- elFinder -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/elfinder/js/elfinder.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/elfinder/js/i18n/elfinder.nl.js"></script>

<!-- JQuery UI -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/js/jquery-ui/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/js/jquery-ui/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.timepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/js/jquery-ui/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/js/jquery-ui/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.droppable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/js/jquery-ui/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.selectable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/js/jquery-ui/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/js/jquery-ui/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/js/jquery-ui/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/js/jquery-ui/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/js/jquery-ui/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>
```

Let me know ;)

Comment: I just did, but no luck :) Can this really make a difference?

Comment: elFinder has been working fine until today when I got the same error about the jQuery UI configuration. I had links to `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css` and `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js`. Turns out that changing the version to `1.8.21` made is start working again (jQuery needs to be `1.7.2`).