# grails elfinder plugin: preview does not work

Tags: grails, preview, elfinder

I'm using elfinder plugin in my grails project, but I have problems with preview. Infact, if I select one image (gif, png, jpeg) and I try to preview it, I only see a black window.
Any suggestion about how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several hours of digging finally got the desired result.

Problem is with the order of `js` inclusion. Following is my **working** gsp page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://elfinder.org/demo/css/elfinder.min.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="elfinder"></div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://elfinder.org/demo/js/elfinder.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var elf = $('#elfinder').elfinder({
                url: '${g.createLink(controller: 'elfinderConnector')}'
            }).elfinder('instance');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ref:- [Issue including elFinder and JQuery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802990/issue-including-elfinder-and-jquery-ui)

**You can get working grails application from my git repo:** <kbd>[elFinder Demo @GIT](https://github.com/manishkbharti/elFinderDemo)</kbd>

Comment: It works! but it only shows images...is it possible to have a preview also for pdfs and text files?

Comment: @FrancescoDS - I am the author of the plugin, if it's a plugin issue, can you please file a bug

Comment: @FrancescoDS - previews for pdf/text files arent supported