# Grails elfinder plugin not working

Tags: grails, plugins, gsp, elfinder

I want to use a file manager in Grails (2.3.11) and found the [elfinder plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/elfinder-connector). I've read the docs and a [related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20451585/4701396) and still the manager does not render on my page. Here is the relevant parts of code. Hopefully someone can help.

Here is my `index.gsp`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main"/>
    <title>File manager</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://elfinder.org/demo/css/elfinder.min.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div id="elfinder"></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://elfinder.org/demo/js/elfinder.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {
        var elf = $('#elfinder').elfinder({
            url: '${g.createLink(controller: 'elfinderConnector')}'
        }).elfinder('instance');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`BuildConfig.groovy`

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"
grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.27'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1100-jdbc41'
        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0-grails-2.3"
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.54"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.0.3"
        compile ':cache:1.1.7'
        compile ":elfinder-connector:0.1"
        compile ":elfinder-resources:2.0.0"
        compile ":ckeditor:4.5.4.1"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.16" // or ":hibernate4:4.3.5.4"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
        runtime ":resources:1.2.8"
        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0.1"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.1"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

        // An alternative to the default resources plugin is the asset-pipeline plugin
        //compile ":asset-pipeline:1.6.1"

        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.5.5"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.5.3"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.5.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.1"
    }
}
```

In `Config.groovy`
`grails.plugin.elfinder.rootDir="C:\\"`

It shouldn't conflict but here is my layout `main.gsp`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title><g:layoutTitle default="Grails"/></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'favicon.ico')}" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'apple-touch-icon.png')}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'apple-touch-icon-retina.png')}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'main.css')}" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'mobile.css')}" type="text/css">
    <g:layoutHead/>
    %{--<g:javascript library="application"/>--}%
    <r:layoutResources/>

</head>

<body>
<div id="grailsLogo" role="banner"><a href="http://grails.org"><img
        src="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'grails_logo.png')}" alt="Grails"/></a></div>
<g:layoutBody/>
<div class="footer" role="contentinfo"></div>

<div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;"><g:message code="spinner.alt" default="Loading&hellip;"/></div>
<r:layoutResources/>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: any errors in stacktrace or in the frontend console?

Comment: @Michal_Szulc no stacktrace errors. There are front-end errors:

`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://studio-42.github.io/elFinder/". (index):21 |                       

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < (index):1  |

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).elfinder is not a function index:38`

Answer (score 0):

First of all: you are using really old [plugin](https://github.com/snimavat/grails-elfinder-connector), which wasn't maintained for 5 years now. You are asking for trouble.

However according to the error:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://studio-42.github.io/elFinder/". (index):21
```

**http://elfinder.org/demo/css/elfinder.min.css** is not a correct css file so resources can not be loaded. Similar situation is related with **http://elfinder.org/demo/js/elfinder.min.js** which is incorrect js filepath.

If you want to use elfinder, stick to the fresh version and docs: https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder

Comment: The reason why I went with the plugin is because the raw version you linked to requires PHP. How do I make that work with Grails? My app is being developed in a Windows environment and will eventually be deployed as a war file to a linux server (i'm not the admin for the linux server).

Comment: https://github.com/Studio-42/elfinder-servlet `Please note this project is not maintained by anyone and if you would like to participate contact us at dev@std42.ru`. You can always take care of this open source project